# How to increment a variable from lambda-functor's body?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I tried to increment a local variable from lambda expression:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T foo(T t){
    T temp{};
    [temp]() -> void { 
        temp++; 
    }();
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<< foo(10) << std::endl;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a358b3bb0e3533e8)

But got the following error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'foo(T)::<lambda()> [with T = int]':

main.cpp:6:6:   required from 'struct foo(T) [with T = int]::<lambda()>'

main.cpp:8:6:   required from 'T foo(T) [with T = int]'

main.cpp:14:23:   required from here

main.cpp:7:13: error: increment of read-only variable 'temp'

         temp++; 

             ^
```

Is there some workaround about that in c++11/14?

Answer (score 7):

`temp` cannot be modified when it's captured by copy in a non-mutable lambda.

You could capture `temp` by reference:

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T t){
    T temp{};
    [&temp]() -> void { 
        temp++; 
    }();
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to capture a variable by value and modify it, you need to mark the lambda `mutable`:

```
[temp]() mutable -> void {
//       ^^^^^^^ 
    temp++; 
}();
```

This allows the body to modify the parameters captured by value, and to call their non-const member functions

Comment: Will it just modify the copied one, and has nothing to do with the outer `temp`? http://ideone.com/pCwE3N

Comment: @songyuanyao: yes. :-)

Comment: @songyuanyao Yeah, it's still a by-value capture, regardless of mutability.

Comment: I see, thanks. Might be better to mention about that, I think it conflicts with OP's original intent.

Answer (score 3):

It's C++14, so you can simplify your lambda.
That said, these are some valid solutions (I assume that you want to change the value of the original variable, not of a copy of it):

- capture by reference:

  `[&temp]() { temp++; }();`

(you must guarantee that the lifetime of `temp` outcomes the one of the lambda)

- copy back and forth:

  `temp = [temp = temp]() mutable { return ++temp; }();`

(you are not requested to guarantee that the lifetime of `temp` outcomes the one of the lambda)

- move back and forth:

  `temp = [temp{std::move(temp)}]() mutable { temp++; return std::move(temp); }();`

(you are not requested to guarantee that the lifetime of `temp` outcomes the one of the lambda)

And so on...

Comment: It makes me happy to see someone using C++14's capture initializers, so have a +1. But because of how the lambda is being used, I don't think anything beyond C++11's syntax is necessary here.

Comment: @JonathanMee I know, you're right, but it was a good chance to use them!! :-)

Comment: honestly the thing that I wanted C++14 to give us is the ability to define temporaries in the capture list, like `[int i{}] { return ++i; }` and even though it's been discussed, it still isn't available in C++17 :(

Comment: @JonathanMee Why can't you define them in the body of the lambda? I don't fully get the need of that, sorry...

Comment: Oh, there's no particular need for it, but in discussions variables declared in the capture would be static. So calling `[int i{}] { return ++i; }` 3x would return 3. This is particularly helpful in one of the standard algorithms where you need to index along with iteration. For example, given: `vector<int> foo(13)` You could initialize to a range like this: `transform(begin(foo), end(foo), [int i{}](auto& it){*it = ++i;})` The issue with this of course is where is the space for `i` allocated? And what if this was called in a function which was called multiple times, does `i` reset?

Comment: @JonathanMee Wow, it sounds interesting. Thank you for your responses. Really appreciated.

Comment: @JonathanMee : FWIW, `[i = int{}]() mutable { return ++i; }` works fine. See e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea89eec9ffd80eef I feel like I'm missing your point.. ;-]

Answer (score 2):

What you mean by "local variable" is a bit ambiguous.

1. To increment `foo`'s `temp` you'll need to [capture by reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), so your lambda will look like: `[&temp] { temp++; }`
2. To increment the lambda's `temp` you'll need to [use the `mutable` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation), so your lambda will look like: `[temp]() mutable { temp++; }`

It seems unlikely that you're trying to do **2** because any changes that you make will be lost on the return of the lambda, since it's not returning anything. And, in the example you've given you do not further use `temp` in the lambda.

So presuming you're trying to do **1**, you'll need to make sure that `T` is not a reference and not `const`. Either of these examples would get you in trouble:

```
const auto t = 1;
foo(t);
```

or

```
auto& t = bar;
foo(t);
```

To avoid both of these you should define `foo`'s `temp` with [`decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
decay_t<T> temp{};
```